# cambiar version de java 9 a 8 en mac

Tags: ionic, java-8, macos, terminal

estoy mordicando un proyecto en ionic 1 y como tengo instalado el java 9 no me deja exportar a android  y me sale este error `Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater`. No se mucho de mac, podrian decirme ¿como cambiar la version desde el terminal?, ya instalé el jdk 8

Comment: Según [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40629927/5587982), para no tener problemas posteriores, desinstala todas las versiones de JDK y luego instala sólo el JDK 1.8. Una solución, que ha funcionado s+olo en algunos casos es ejecutar esto: `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` desde la terminal.

Comment: @A.Cedano vale gracias, pero ese comando `update-alternatives` no lo reconoce coom u comando, hay una pagina para instalarlo?

Comment: La segunda opción, como te decía, no ha funcionado en todos los casos y al parecer no funciona para instalaciones manuales. Creo que lo mejor será desinstalar todas las versiones de JDK que tengas y dejar instalada sólo la [versión 1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html). En caso de que necesites ambas, tendrás entonces que cambiar la versión en el archivo de configuración de Java